# Why does the If-Else Statement jumps not into else?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a problem, I dont see yet. I guess it has something to do with the andalso or IsNot operator.

So for shure my Value of Cells(o)  is "ImportName" but it nevertheless jumps not into else.
It tries to Change value of .cells(1)

```
If row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "ImportName" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "ID" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "CSV_Datensatznummer" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "ist_headerzeile" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "Einlese_Datum" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "Dubletten_Vorschlaege" _
           AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "forcerequestid" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_Update_erfolgreich" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "adress_korrektur_noetig" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "adress_korrektur_abgeschlossen" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "in_Adrium_angelegt" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "fehler_bei_der_anlage" _
           AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "import_abgeschlossen" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_dubletten_vorschlaege" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_forcerequerstid" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_fehler_bei_der_anlage" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_in_Adrium_angelegt" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_import_abgeschlossen" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "Update_erfolgreich" _
           AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "Fehler_Update" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_Update_erfolgreich" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_Fehler_Update" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "anreichern_fehler" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_anreichern_fehler" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "Dateiname" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "addresssource_val" AndAlso row.Cells(0).Value IsNot "asp_addresssource_val" Then

                            row.Cells(1).Value = Startseite.Spaltennamen(i)
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Yolo why it doesnt work")

                        End If
```

Comment: A List(Of String) with the forbidden words and a call to Contains would render this code thousands of times more clearer and you will remove the problem

Answer (score 3):

> the Value of `Cells(0)` is "ImportName" but it nevertheless jumps not
>   into the `Else`

The [`IsNot` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3bat82c.aspx) determines if two object references refer to different objects. However, it **does not perform value comparisons**. If you want to compare with non-nothing values simply use `=` and `<>`:

```
Dim value As String = row.Cells(0).Value
If value <> "ImportName" AndAlso value <> "ID" AndAlso value <> "CSV_Datensatznummer" AndAlso value <> "ist_headerzeile" AndAlso value <> "Einlese_Datum" AndAlso value <> "Dubletten_Vorschlaege" _ 
'...'
```

I use `Is` or `IsNot` only for `Nothing`.

You can make the code above more readable and maintainable by using a collection and `Enumerable.Contains`. Also consider that .NET is case sensitive, here is an insensitive comparison:

```
Dim values = { "ImportName", "CSV_Datensatznummer", "ist_headerzeile", "Einlese_Datum", "Dubletten_Vorschlaege" }
If values.Contains(row.Cells(0).Value, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) Then
    ' ... '
Else
    ' ... '
End If
```